# restrict SSH connection to specific URL/domain name

Tags: url, ssh, dns

I have a server with 2 domain names (let's say domain1.com and domain2.com).
I can SSH into the server by `ssh user@domain1.com` and `ssh user@domain2.com`. I would like to be able to only allow `ssh user@domain1.com` and disable SSH acces to domain2.com.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not seem possible to allow SSH connection only to specific domain name. The domain name is resolved by the DNS and there is no way for the SSH server to know which domain you are using. See also [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/disable-ssh-ability-for-specific-domains) answer to the same question.

One thing you might try to do is to configure a firewall (for example [iptable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables)) to drop connection to domain2.com on port 22.

A similar problem was discussed [here](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1055023), where they were trying to block a domain in iptables so that visitor could not access the http server using it.

Adjusting the iptables rule to your case ( and assuming that your ssh server is running on port 22) I would try this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m string --string "Host: domain2.com" --algo bm -j DROP
```

**UPDATE**:

As Dusan Bajic commented the rule above would only work for http traffic because it take advantage of the [http header fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). This would not work for ssh traffic.

Comment: The first paragraph of the answer is correct, the rest could apply only to HTTP traffic and does not make much sense for SSH.